# Understand RandomizedSearchCV output

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search

I am trying to do hyperparameter tunning for the Randomforest regression model.
I'm using RandomizedSearchCV (scikit-learn) and I defined verbose=10.
For that reason, I'm getting messaged while it's running and I would like to understand them a bit better.

Those are my parameters for RandomizedSearchCV:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
# Use the random grid to search for best hyperparameters
# First create the base model to tune
rf = RandomForestRegressor(-1)


with parallel_backend('threading',n_jobs=12):
    rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 12, cv = 3, verbose=10, random_state=42)#, n_jobs = -2)
    # Fit the random search model
    rf_random.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

After running a while )and is still running) I have those messages:

[image]

**my questions are:**
**1. what are the rows before the first red row? I thought it may be the combinations of parameters but** **that doesn't make a lot of sense because those are not enough**
**2. What is the meaning of the row between the red rows? Why those parameters are there? is this after one CV?**
**3. "Done one task" - what is the task? one CV?**
**4. Why do I get score only to some of the parameters?**

Answer (score 2):

> *1. what are the rows before the first red row? I thought it may be the combinations of parameters but that doesn't make a lot of sense because those are not enough*

Parameters, which are the candidates of the CV are printed

> *2. What is the meaning of the row between the red rows? Why those parameters are there? is this after one CV?*

It is printed after the completion of the 3rd(as defined in your code) fold for a parameter Candidate

> *3. "Done one task" - what is the task? one CV?*

This is from the joblib I believe. It's the completion of one fold *i.e. one out of 36.*

> *4. Why do I get a score only for some of the parameters?*

The score is printed after the completion of 3(as defined in your code) fold of each parameter candidate

*In a multi-thread setup, we can't rely on the sequence of the messages as it will depend on the Thread allocation.*

**My answer is based on this small setup.**

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
iris = load_iris()
logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='saga', tol=1e-2, random_state=0)

distributions = dict(C=[0.1,0.5,1.0],
                      penalty=['l2', 'l1'], max_iter=[50,100])
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(logistic, distributions, random_state=0,n_iter = 5, cv = 2, verbose=10)

from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
with parallel_backend('threading',n_jobs=12):
    search = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

#### Output

> Fitting 2 folds for each of 5 candidates, totalling 10 fits
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.5 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.5 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l1, max_iter=100, C=1.0 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l1, max_iter=100, C=1.0 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=50, C=0.5 ..................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=50, C=0.5 ..................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=1.0 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=1.0 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.1 .................................
>
> [CV] penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.1 .................................
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=1.0, score=0.960, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.5, score=0.973, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.1, score=0.947, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l1, max_iter=100, C=1.0, score=0.973, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=1.0, score=0.973, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ...... penalty=l2, max_iter=50, C=0.5, score=0.973, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.1, score=0.893, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l2, max_iter=100, C=0.5, score=0.960, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ...... penalty=l2, max_iter=50, C=0.5, score=0.960, total=   0.0s
>
> [CV] ..... penalty=l1, max_iter=100, C=1.0, score=0.987, total=   0.0s

> [Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
>
> [Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done   3 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.1s
>
> [Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done   5 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
>
> [Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done   7 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
>
> [Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.0s finished